# how to replace view with another view in backbone.js on runtime

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to build backbone.js application with twitter API.
the application that I am working on performs 3 tasks:1-returns the recent tweets on the user 's timeline, 2-returns the user profile 3- provides the ability to search in twitter. my problem is that I want the results of the search functionality to appear in the location of the tweets when the user clicks the search button. in my code there is view to display the tweets and another view to display the results of searching..how to put view in the place of another view on runtime. here is some of the code to explain the idea:
 index.html :

```
  <body>
   <header role="banner">
   <!—some code here-->       
   </header>
   <div id="search" class="inner-search">
             <form>
             <label>Search for</label>
     <input type="search" id="searchbox" style="width: 70%;" 
                    autofocus="" placeholder="I'm looking for.."/>
                <button id="searchbutton" style="width: 10%;">Go</button>
            </form>
         </div><!--search-view-->
   <div class="inner-content">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="chapter-list">
                ………            
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div role="main" class="main-content metrouicss">
        <div id='timeline' class='timeline-view'>
             <h3>Tweets </h3>
         </div>
    </div><!--main-->

  <div role="right" class="right-content">
     <h3>My Profile </h3>
     <div id="profile" class="profile-view">
     <!-- This would be the template -->                                
     </div></div><!--right-->
  </div> <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer role="contentinfo">
    <div class="inner-footer">
        <p class="copyright">&copy; Eva Hriekes, 2015. All rights 
  reserved.</p>
    </div> <!-- /.inner-footer -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Template for profile -->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="profile-template">
  <div class='tiles clearfix'>
    <div class="tile double bg-color-orangeDark">
      <div class="tile-content">
          <img src="{{user.profile_image_url}}" class="place-left">
          <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">{{user.name}}</h3>
          <p style="float:left;">{{user.description}}</p>
          <div class="brand">
              <div class="badge">{{user.followers_count}} Followers</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
  <!-- Template for timeline -->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="timeline-template">
   <ul class='listview fluid'>
      {{#each tweet}}
    <li >
        <div class='icon'>
            <img src='{{user.profile_image_url}}'></img>
        </div>
        <div class='data'>
              <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
              <p>{{format text}}</p>
              <p class="timestamp" style="text-decoration:underline;">
              <i>{{friendlyDate}}</i></p>
              <p style="font-weight:bold;">Rating:&nbsp;
              <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-
              o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-
              o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></p>
        </div>
    </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </script>

   <!-- Template for search results -->

   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="search-template">
   <ul class='listview fluid'>
      {{#each tweet}}
    <li >
        <div class='icon'>
            <img src='{{user.profile_image_url}}'></img>
        </div>
        <div class='data'>
              <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
              <p>{{format text}}</p>
              <p class="timestamp" style="text-decoration:underline;">
     <i>{{friendlyDate}}</i></p>
        </div>
    </li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </script>

  <script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

timeline view:

```
     define(['jquery', 'handlebars', 'backbone', 'app/collection
     /Timeline','app/view/ProfilePopupView'],
     function($, Handlebars, Backbone, Timeline,ProfilePopupView) {

     var com = com || {};
     com.apress = com.apress || {};
     com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {};

     com.apress.view.TimelineView = Backbone.View.extend({

      el: '#timeline',

    template: Handlebars.compile($("#timeline-template").html()),

    timeline: null,
    events: {
    'click .profile': 'showDialog'
     },

     initialize:  function(options){
    var self = this; 

    //create a collection for this view to render 
    self.timeline = new Timeline();//new
   com.apress.collection.Timeline();
    //initial render 
    self.render();

    //force the fetch to fire a reset event
    self.timeline.fetch({reset:true 
        });

    self.listenTo(self.timeline, 'reset', self.render);

  },

render: function(){
    var self = this; 
    if(self.timeline.models.length > 0){
        var output = self.template({tweet: self.timeline.toJSON()});

        self.$el.append(output);            
    }
    return self; 
},
showDialog: function(options){

    var self =this, 
        $target = $(options.currentTarget),
        username = $target.data('user'); 

    /** 
     * Reuse the profile view
     **/
    var profileView = new ProfilePopupView({user: username});

}

 });


// export stuff:
return com.apress.view.TimelineView;
});
```

search view:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

var com = com || {};
com.apress = com.apress || {};
com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {};

com.apress.view.SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#search',

model: null,

events: {
     'click #searchbutton': 'runSearch'

},

initialize:  function(options){
    var self = this; 
    self.model = options.model;
},

runSearch: function(e){
    var self = this;
        query = $('#searchbox').val();

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Run search against  ' +  query);
    //force a reset
    self.model.set('query', '', {silent: true});
    self.model.set('query', query);
}


});

return com.apress.view.SearchView; 
});
```

results view:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'handlebars','dialog'], function($,
 Backbone, Handlebars,Dialog) {

 var com = com || {};
 com.apress = com.apress || {};
 com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {};

com.apress.view.ResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#results',  /* or should be el="#timeline"???*/

model: null,


template: Handlebars.compile($("#search-template").html()),

initialize:  function(options){
    var self = this; 
    self.model = options.model;

    self.model.fetch({
            error: function(e){
                self.model.trigger("app:error", {message: 'Error
   retrieving timeline information'});
            }, 
        success: function(e){
                self.model.trigger("app:success", {message: 'success 
   retrieving timeline information'});
            }

    });

    self.listenTo(self.model,'change', self.render);

    self.render();
  },

 render: function(){
    console.log('Display now');
                        var self = this,
    output = self.template({tweet: self.model.get('statuses')});

      /* I want to delete this code and display the results
     in the place of tweets*/
    $.Dialog({
            'title'       : 'Search Results',
            'content'     : output,
            'draggable'   : true,
            'overlay'     : true,
            'closeButton' : true,
            'buttonsAlign': 'center',
            'keepOpened'  : true,
            'position'    : {
                'zone'    : 'left'
            },
            'buttons'     : {
                'OK'     : {
                    'action': function(){}
                }
            }
        });

            }   

     });
    return com.apress.view.ResultsView; 
   });
```

can anyone help me in doing what I want?

Comment: Don't use `el: '#id'` in any views, let views create and manage their own `el`s. The caller adds views to a container as needed and calls [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on the old view before adding the new one.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use Marionette. The Layout will fit your requirement nicely, and you'll remove most of your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how to let views create and manage their own el s? I dont have much experience in backbone. can u explain more how to do this in code i.e what I should change in my code to work correctly?@mu is too short

Comment: I have read about marionette but until now I cant work with it perfectly, so do u have a solution to use in my current code?? and maybe when I learn more about marionette I will use it.@Roman